# Codeigniter active record: adding a dynamic variable to result name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there a way to add a dynamic variable to codeigniter's active record result name?

im trying to do something like this

in my database i have these columns

```
UID    row1    row2    row3   and so on
1      a       b       c      etc
```

and im trying echo out each of these columns by making the number after column name into a dynamic variable

for example

```
for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++){
    echo $query->row.$x;
}
```

however doing it this way doesnt work

is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: do you want to make row1,row2,row3 and so on dynamic.i.e row is common for all but only 1 ,2 , 3 will be dynamic?

Comment: yes the word row is static while 1,2,3 is dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line solution

```
for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++)
{
    echo $test->{"row$x"};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++){
    $key='row'.$x;
    echo $result->$key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am correct then you can do that

```
for($x=1;$x<=10;$x++){
    echo $query['row'.$x];
}
```

i think this should work.